# SSIS relative flat file source path

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm building a package, that will be shared among other people in order to load some data and I'd like it to be dynamic as much as possible.

At the moment I'm struggling with relative path names in *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*.

Currently I have File Name set as `.\Source\ComTrade\Import.csv` and once I click preview, then I can see all of my records. Screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

However once I run my package it does not find my file and I get these error messages:

```
[Source - All imports in file [85]] Information: The processing of file ".\Source\ComTrade\Import.csv" has started.
[Source - All imports in file [85]] Warning: The system cannot find the path specified.
[Source - All imports in file [85]] Error: Cannot open the datafile ".\Source\ComTrade\Import.csv".
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Source - All imports in file failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.
```

How can I use such file naming conventions in SSIS?

Comment: Why dont use a project parameter where you can specify root folder and then you can use expressions to specify full file path in flat file source? The package is failing because the execution path is different when package is executed.

Comment: What version of SSIS? Where is the package running? Maybe that path is not valid from where the package is running

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm running that on VS2015 DataTools if that helps. I run this package locally on my machine, not on Server.

Comment: I guess the `.` part of your oath now relates the location of `DTExec.EXE`, not the visual studio exe. To make a package flexible use parameters - relative paths are not the answer because when you deploy this to an SSIS server it changes again